# Bug report: details for graph showing my rep don't include an answer that earned rep within the graphs selected time period

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-graph

The graph shows rep from 10/14 through 10/15.

I posted an answer 10/14 that currently has 2 upvotes, but it isn't listed in the details to the right of the graph.

I have screenshots of both the graphs and the question, if you want them (ctrager@yahoo.com).

This is a link the the answer whose points are not counted.
[What is the cleverest UI feature you have seen in a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543107/what-is-the-cleverest-ui-feature-you-have-seen-in-a-website/1569910#1569910)

This is a link to the page with the graph.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/9328?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bug - the answer you linked to is Community Wiki, meaning that you didn't actually get any reputation from it, and that's why it's not in the graph.